# how to send image base64 to django server from flutter

Tags: python, django, flutter, python-requests, flutter-dependencies

Can someone help me with this? I am sending an image from flutter to django (python) server. I am successfully in taking the image from mobile
camera/gallery and converting(encoded) the image to base64.

**Flutter code:**

```
 Future classifyImage() async{
if(imageFile==null) return;
  String base64Image = base64Encode(imageFile.readAsBytesSync());
String fileName = imageFile.path.split("/").last;
http.post(phpEndPoint, body:
{
  "image" : base64Image,
  //"name" : fileName,
}).then((res) {
  print(res.body);
}).catchError((err) {
  print(err);
//print(base64Image);
//print(fileName);
});
}
```

[here is the converted string in flutter by base64](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRGVE.png)

```
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQICAQEBAQMCAgICAwMEBAMDAwMEBAYFBAQFBAMDBQcFBQYGBgYGBAUHBwcGBwYGBgb/2wBDAQEBAQEBAQMCAgMGBAMEBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgb/wAARCAPXAy0DASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAgICAwEBAQAAAAAAAAAABgcEBQMIAAIJAQoL/8QAaBAAAQMDAwIEAwQFBwQJEAITAQIDEQAEIQUSMQZBEyJRYQcycRRCgZEICSNSoRUzYnKxtMEWN3bRCiRDZHSChJLwFyY2U1ZjZWZzhZSipbO14Sc0NUR1g5WkGEWTJSg4RkdXWHej8f/EABcBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAQP/xAAaEQEAAwEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgMyATER/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwDzr/2W4wXv0yf0cSCRH6MDY/8Abuo1+SpOmqUoJEyTzX66/wDZZbC3v0x/0dClBUB+jG3JA/8ADmo1+U6ysFF9uWiM+lXZvqY5DbfTDy07hvIA4FW+n9E3Nw4ghLme4px6ZpqC2NyEkd5FMbp/SrfcgKQ2M+lQomrHogtIAcSQoeoq7Z6SS2UmAY4pwa1Zhq6CGmgRnKRUZixddKR4RAjPloAS20YNH5AcZxV41aBsD9mD6YpgWnTy3YBQoe8VeNdIKWAYI9hQK9Ol/avOGgkTkRU9jQCCP2ZwKbNv019nSEFAk8kirVnQgIGz+FAqWNBOPJ/CrRvQDM7DEelNpnQhjyfhFWzegDEJ+hIoF7pekFpopKYxgRVujTck7e1HrOjBsQUYqa1pSceWgB2dLKgPKffFWKNJMfIaOmdMAgBP8KsEaanAKe1AGWmn7EREGPSpYssj/VRWLMIJAQRHEiu6bOe0fhQDKbPvH8KzC0BE8fhRKizjEc94rKLIA8A+o20
```

Now, the problem is the string which is received in django server is different from the string which is converted in flutter.

[here is the string which is received in django server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5yLF.jpg)

**Python code:**

```
@csrf_exempt
def android_predict(request):
try : 
    print('Request method is : ' + request.method)
    if request.method == 'POST' :
        print('method is POST')
        print('Body is : ' + str(request.body))
        decoded = request.body.decode("UTF-8")
        print(decoded)
        name_image = decoded.split('&')[1].split('=')[1]
        print('name is : ' + name_image)
        b64_image = decoded.split('&')[0].split('=')[1]
        print('Base64 image is : ' + b64_image)
        missing_padding = len(b64_image)%4
        print('Length is : ' + str(len(b64_image)))
        if missing_padding : 
            b64_image += '='*(4-missing_padding)
        print('Modified Base64 image is : ' + b64_image)
        print('New length is : ' + str(len(b64_image)))
        image = PIL.Image.open(io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode(b64_image)))
        target_image = image.resize((500,500),PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
        print(type(target_image))
        image_array = np.array(target_image)
        image_file, x1 = predict_image(image_array,name_image)
        # image = PIL.Image.open(io.BytesIO(b64_image))
        context_dict = {'statusCode' : 0, 'statusMessage' : 'working', 'prediction' : x1}
    else :
        print('method is GET')
        context_dict = {'statusCode' : 1, 'statusMessage' : 'request type is not post'}
    print(context_dict)
    return JsonResponse(context_dict, safe=False)
except : 
    context_dict = {'statusCode' : 1, 'statusMessage' : 'exception occurred'}
    print(context_dict)
    return JsonResponse(context_dict, safe=False)
```

Comment: the headers are wrong i guess, that is why you are receiving the wrong String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you send to server in base64 String, convert encording urlencode

```
var encoded = Uri.encodeFull(base64String);
```

and in server your string value convert

urldecording -> base64decording